Name for Operators on Sequences
Is there some terminology for an operator $O$ that maps sequences to sequences such that the elements of the sequence $O(a)$ are given by
$$\bigl(O(a)\bigr)_n ~{}={}~ \sup_{k \geq n}\, a_k~?$$
I believe $O(a)$ is something like the tightest monotonically decreasing sequence that dominates $a$.
Similarly, I am looking for a name of an operator that does an inf instead of a sup.
